# Passenger 6.0.8 loaded as an NGINX module fails to start up

Tags: passenger

New builds using Passenger 6.0.8 fail to start up because of file permission issues. Passenger is being loaded as a module in NGINX.

```
 2021/04/06 01:41:46 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/usr/share/nginx/passenger_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Same configuration works fine in 6.0.7. What parameter needs to be updated for the path above?

Comment: I managed to get it to start again by setting `passenger_temp_path /tmp/passenger_temp`, but I'm not sure how secure this is (although I imagine systemd's `PrivateTmp` helps).